# Getting error in c# when i hit endpoint of google dialog-flow but same google dialog-flow endpoint is working in postman

Tags: c#, postman

I am using this Endpoint in PostMan:-

https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910

And this JSON string i am sending:-

```
{"query":"flights from NYC to Vadodara","sessionId":"6b9d4676-2a71-4c64-a562-8c08f198c623","lang":"pt-BR","resetContexts":false}
```

And I am setting Content-type and Authorization in postman.

All these things are perfectly working in postman but the problem is when I hit this endpoint using c# code is not working its give me this error:-

Error I am getting:-

```
{
  "id": "7b0ac743-58ea-4d61-a41d-a299f086a816",
  "timestamp": "2018-06-04T15:30:25.873Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "status": {
    "code": 400,
    "errorType": "bad_request",
    "errorDetails": "Invalid request content type, expecting \"multipart/form-data\" or \"application/json; charset\u003dutf-8."
  }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
using ApiAi.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "xxx");

            var response = http.PostAsync("https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910", new StringContent(new Program().getSessionID(new ConfigModel { AccesTokenClient = "xxx" }, "flights from NYC to Vadodara"))).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        public string getSessionID(ConfigModel config, string message)
        {
            var requestData = new RequestModel
            {
                query = message,
                sessionId = (config.SessionId ?? Guid.NewGuid()).ToString(),
                lang = "pt-BR"
            };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
        }
    }
    public class RequestModel
    {
        public string query { get; set; }
        public string sessionId { get; set; }
        public string lang { get; set; }
        public bool resetContexts { get; set; }
    }
}








//  
// Copyright (c) 2017 Nick Rimmer. All rights reserved.  
// Licensed under the MIT License. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.  
//

using ApiAi.Enums;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApiAi.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Services configuration
    /// </summary>
    public class ConfigModel
    {
        #region magic
        internal static string 
            BaseUrl = @"https://api.dialogflow.com/v1",
            VersionCode = @"20150910";

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Each API request requires authentication to identify the agent that is responsible for making the request. Authentication is provided through an access token.
        /// The developer access token is used for managing entities and intents.
        /// </summary>
        public string AccesTokenDeveloper { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Each API request requires authentication to identify the agent that is responsible for making the request. Authentication is provided through an access token.
        /// The client access token is used for making queries.
        /// </summary>
        public string AccesTokenClient { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifed language in your Api.ai agent
        /// </summary>
        public LanguagesEnum Language { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Timezone requests parameter
        /// </summary>
        public string TimeZone { get; set; } = System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Session ID for request
        /// </summary>
        public object SessionId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

This is code i am using.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [StringContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138198(v=vs.118).aspx) itself has an overload to set the content type:

```
var response = http.PostAsync(yourUrl, 
                              new StringContent("your json string",
                                                 Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                   .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The default media type is set to: `text/plain`

Ps: you might want to split these in more readable functions. It helps when debugging.

**The documentation is pretty vague on this one**, but as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx), `StringContent` has it's own `Headers` property. My guess is that it will override your request headers.

Decompiling the assembly reveals a default value for the mediatype, as you can see is `text/plain`:

```
/// <summary>Creates a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.StringContent" /> class.</summary>
/// <param name="content">The content used to initialize the <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.StringContent" />.</param>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public StringContent(string content)
  : this(content, (Encoding) null, (string) null)
{
}

/// <summary>Creates a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.StringContent" /> class.</summary>
/// <param name="content">The content used to initialize the <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.StringContent" />.</param>
/// <param name="encoding">The encoding to use for the content.</param>
/// <param name="mediaType">The media type to use for the content.</param>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public StringContent(string content, Encoding encoding, string mediaType)
  : base(StringContent.GetContentByteArray(content, encoding))
{
  this.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType == null ? "text/plain" : mediaType)
  {
    CharSet = encoding == null ? HttpContent.DefaultStringEncoding.WebName : encoding.WebName
  };
}
```

PS: you can also try:

```
//since utf-8 is the default.
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
```

Comment: Thank you so much But can you please explain more why I need to pass this two parameters Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"

Comment: yes its work but can you help me to clear my concepts??

Comment: And sorry I am not able to upward your answer because of low reputation

Comment: Yes, ok.... well; first I thought this wouldn't help because, as you said; you are sending the headers. Nevertheless, I updated the answer. And gave you some points so hopefully you can upvote XD ... I think you would be able to mark it as answer though

Comment: I need 4 more points to upward your answer because now my reputation is 11 I need 15 to upward the answer.

Comment: Marking it as answer (the big grey V) will give you 2 more points.... not sure if the same limitation counts.